What is the relation of the glueing cocycle and two one-forms of a connection.
While taking a course in Index Theorem and Characteristic Classes, we encountered the topics of connections and vector bundles and a simple doubt that I have been unable to answer myself: (I will write down practically all that I know and have thought in regards to the doubt that I have, wich is down below)
First, considering a vector bundle over $\mathbb{R}$, we defined a connection on a vector bundle as the following map as the following:
$$\nabla: \Gamma^{\infty}(E)\rightarrow\Gamma^{\infty}(T^{*}M\otimes E)$$
Where:

$\Gamma^{\infty}(E)$ is the space of smooth sections of $E$ the total space of the vector bundle.
$M$ is the base space and thus $T^{*}M$ is the cotangent bundle of $M$.

Also, we know that the connection has the following properties:

Is $\mathbb{R}$-linear.
If we take $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$, and $s\in \Gamma^{\infty}(E)$ then the following is true
$$\nabla(fs)=df\otimes s + f \cdot \nabla s.$$

If we now take trivialization charts $\{(u_{\alpha},\psi_{\alpha})\}$:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
E|_{u_{\alpha}} @>{\psi_{\alpha}}>> U_{\alpha}\times\mathbb{R}^{r}\\
@VVV \Large\swarrow \\
u_{i} 
\end{CD}$$
The trivialization is the same as the choice of the local frame in $E|_{u_{\alpha}}$, so there is a local frame of sections $e_{1}(x)\dots e_{r}(x)\in E_{x}$ with $x\in u_{\alpha}$ that is linearly independent and so we can relate it to $\psi$ in the following way:
$$e_{j}(x)=\psi^{-1}_{\alpha}(x,(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0))$$.
With this, we can write a specific equation for a section $s(x)\in\Gamma^{\infty}(E|_{u_{\alpha}})$:
$$s(x)=\sum_{a}s^{a}(x)e_{a}(x).$$
where $s^{a}(x)\in C^{\infty}(u_{x})$ are coefficients, and $e_{a}(x)$ are vector fields.
Given this, I had my first question or doubt:

Can we write the connection in terms of $s^{a}$? For that, I manage to answer myself, with the help of books and the Internet:

$$\nabla s(x)=\nabla\big(\sum_{a}s^{a}(x)e_{a}(x)\big)= \sum_{a}\nabla\big(s^{a}(x)e_{a}(x)\big)=\sum_{a}\big(ds^{a}\otimes e_{a}+s^{a}\nabla e_{a}\big)$$
Where $\nabla e_{a}\in\Gamma\infty(T^{*}u_{\alpha}\otimes E|_{u_{\alpha}})$, and we define it as $\nabla e_{c}= \sum_{b}A^{b}_{a}\otimes e_{b}$, where $A^{b}_{a}$ is a one form, so continuing with the above,
$$\nabla s(x)= \sum_{a}(ds^{a}\otimes e_{a}+\sum_{b}s^{a}A^{a}_{b}\otimes e_{b})=\sum_{a}(ds^{a}+\sum_{b}s^{b}A^{a}_{b})\times e_{a}$$
So, we get.
$$(\nabla s)^{a}=ds^{a}+A^{a}_{b}s^{b}.$$
If I'm not wrong, that should be the answer. However, other questions now arise, which, in my opinion, should be easier, but I still haven't solved one. The first one is:

If we change the trivialization what happens to $A$? This question is simple:

Take $A_{\alpha}$ (change of notation so it is more clear) for a trivialization $\{(u_{\alpha},\psi_{\alpha})\}$.
So if we take another trivialization $\{(u_{\beta},\psi_{\beta})\}$, then this defines another one form $A_{\beta}$.
Now the other question and the one I haven't solved is:

What is the relationship between $A_{\alpha}$, $A_{\beta}$ and $g_{\beta\alpha}$ (gluing cocycle)?

So here we need to use the definition of gluing cocycle which is:
$$\psi_{\beta}\circ\psi_{\alpha}^{-1}(x,v)=(x,g_{\beta\alpha}(x)v).$$
where $g_{\beta\alpha}:u_{\beta\alpha}\rightarrow Aut(v)$ and $v$ is a fiber, and has the diagram:
\begin{CD} u_{\beta\alpha}\times\mathbb{R}^{r} @>\psi_{\beta}>> E|_{u_{\beta\alpha}}@>\psi_{\alpha}>>u_{\alpha\beta}\times\mathbb{R}^{r}\\ @.    {_{\rlap{}}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(30deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{4em}{0em}]{}}}}@VVu_{\beta\alpha}V {_{\rlap{}}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(150deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{4em}{0em}]{}}}} \\  @. u_{\beta\alpha} \end{CD}
Here the main idea is to get a relationship between the sections of the two trivializations, let's say a relation between $e^{\alpha}_{a}$ and $e^{\beta}_{a}$ and also between $s^{a}_{\alpha}$ and $s^{a}_{\beta}$.
Here, what I know is that the $s$ are coordinates of the same section, but in different frames and these should be related by the gluing cocycle.
To try to answer the question I asked my professor and he told me that basically I already had the answer written. He also told me that the formula should look something like:
$$A_{\beta}=g^{-1}_{\beta\alpha}A_{\alpha}g^{-1}_{\beta\alpha}\pm g^{-1}_{\beta\alpha}\;dg_{\beta\alpha}$$
but he told me he was not sure and didn't remember.
The thing is that I don't even have a clear idea of how to get to a formula that looks like that, any help would be appreciated.
As to the final comment he told me I should first try to think about the relationship between $e$'s and $s$'s, but I am really lost.

View a local frame $e=\begin{bmatrix}e_1 & \cdots & e_r\end{bmatrix}$ over an open set $U$ as a row vector, and write $\nabla e=eA$ in terms of a matrix-valued 1-form $A$. Express a section $s$ over $U$ as $s=e\cdot \tilde{s}$, where $\tilde{s}:U\to\mathbb{R}^r$ is viewed as a column vector. By the defining properties of a connection, we have $\nabla s=e\cdot (d\tilde{s} + A\tilde{s})$, so the $i$-th component of the vector-valued 1-form $\nabla s$ is $(\nabla s)^i=d\tilde{s}^i+A^i_{\,j} \tilde{s}^j$ (there are typos or problems with dummy variables in your derivation of a similar local expression for $\nabla s$).
Now, given two trivializations $(U_\alpha,\phi_\alpha)$ and $(U_\beta,\phi_\beta)$ with associated local frames $e_\alpha$ and $e_\beta$ respectively. Let $g_{\beta\alpha}=\phi_\beta\circ\phi_\alpha^{-1}:U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\to\mathrm{GL}(r,\mathbb{R})$ and $g_{\alpha\beta}=g_{\beta\alpha}^{-1}$ be the transition functions. Since $(\phi_\alpha e_{\beta,j})^i=(g_{\alpha\beta})^i_{\,j}$, we have $e_{\beta,j}=e_{\alpha,i}(g_{\alpha\beta})^i_{\,j}$ and $e_\beta=e_\alpha g_{\alpha\beta}$. Then
$$
    \nabla e_\beta = \nabla (e_\alpha g_{\alpha\beta})=(\nabla e_\alpha)g_{\alpha\beta}+e_\alpha dg_{\alpha\beta}=e_\alpha A_\alpha g_{\alpha\beta}+e_\alpha dg_{\alpha\beta}=e_\beta\cdot(g_{\beta\alpha}A_\alpha g_{\alpha\beta}+g_{\beta\alpha} dg_{\alpha\beta}).
$$
Therefore, $A_\beta=g_{\beta\alpha}A_\alpha g_{\alpha\beta}+g_{\beta\alpha} dg_{\alpha\beta}=g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1}A_\alpha g_{\alpha\beta}+g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1} dg_{\alpha\beta}$.
Note also that for a general section $s$, its local expressions are related by $s^\beta=g_{\beta\alpha}s^\alpha$ as (column) vector-valued functions.
